# Prove that $\sum_{Y} P(X, Y) = P(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a homework assignment I need to prove that $\sum_{Y} P(X, Y) = P(X)$, given the following properties (Kolmogorov axioms):

For a given set of events $S$ and a probability mass function $P(\cdot)$, we have

1. $P(a) \geq 0 $ for all $a \in S$;
2. $P(S) = \sum_{a \in S}P(a) = 1$;
3. For $A, B \subseteq S$ that satisfy $A \cap B = \emptyset: P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) $
4. $P(A|B) = P(A, B) / P(B)$

It is a homework question, but I am really stuck and would like someone to give me a hint. I understand intuitively why $\sum_{Y} P(X, Y) = P(X)$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Start with what you are given:

$$\sum^Y P(X,Y) $$.

Do you understand the law of total probability?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't know what the total law of probability is. Could you explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Law of Total Probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Honestly, I still don't know how to prove it.